# Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a ash Command

Tags: string, replace, busybox, ash

I need to modify href URLs in several html files on a fairly small embedded system that run ash shell and limited busybox. Sole functions available are:

```
ash, brctl, chmod, cp, dnsd, free, halt, ifconfig, init, kill,ls, mkdir, mknod, mount, mv, ping, poweroff, printf, ps, reboot, rm, route, sh, sleep, syslogd, telnetd, umount, vconfig, wc
```

So, no sed, no echo, etc...
I need to find a pattern matching solution!...

I found this ksh trick:

```
alpha='This is a test string in which the word "test" is replaced.' beta="${alpha//test/replace}"
```

but it does not seem to work on ash: syntax error: Bad substitution

Any help appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The substitution is bad because you are using two forward slashes immediate after alpha.  The pattern you want is ${VARIABLE/FINDSTR/REPLACEMENT}.  For example:

```
A="foobar" && echo ${A/foo/bar}
```

However, there appears to be no command for reading a string from the file into a variable.  That is, no cat, head, tail.

So, without some way to get the data from the HTML file into the script I think you're stuck.